# Intel CPU whine

Tags: 12.04, laptop, cpu, fan, overheating

Since I installed ubuntu 12.04 I started hearing cpu whine again. It's really loud and annoying. I tried setting max_cstate to 2, didn't help. On windows I remember muting the microphone - that fixed it. On ubuntu it doesnt work.

The CPU is Intel i7 720qm, laptop is Asus N71jq.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be more of a hardware problem.

As you say, you had the same issue whilst using Windows so it isn't Ubuntu specific. Muting the Mic might of fixed it but it isn't really a cure.

Do other users with the same model of laptop have any issues?

EDIT : A quick google suggests this model laptop does have noticable 'CPU whine'